# What is the difference between TigerVNC and vnc4server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, vnc

Ubuntu ships with vnc4server which is based on RealVNC.

CentOS ships with TigerVNC, which is based on TightVNC which is based on RealVNC.

Does anyone know feature wise what is different between vnc4server and TigerVNC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is in the supported [RFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFB_protocol) protocol version.

I assume (did't check that) that vnc4server will support newer version.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the down-votes here.  The version of the protocol that is supported is the primary and most notable difference.

Comment: @Zoredache: You edited out the reason. The original form of the answer was nothing more than a guess that would require an independent check (arguably something Sandra could have done herself). I don't think this is very helpful, but actually came back here to leave a comment with an explanation for Michal, who is obviously new here.

Comment: @SvenW: Thanks for down-vote rationale. It's true - I'm new here. I shared what I knew hoping it will be helpful. Didn't know exact supported (set of) versions so I wanted to be honest. I still believe this answer might have been helpful especially being the only one.

Comment: @MichałŠrajer: I agree that your answer is helpful, but in my opinion, this type of answer is betted suited as a comment to the question, as it is pointing in the right direction, but not actually answering the question. This is kind of a grey area though, and anyway I hope you understand that downvotes are nearly never meant personal (and certainly not in this case). Also, I removed the downvote, as Z.'s edit made it a factual answer.

Comment: @SvenW: Thanks. If there was a better (full) answer I would probably just leave the comment. Regards.